# The animation of activities is lost when making a configuration change (Android - Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-activity, transition

I am using ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation to go from Activity A to Activity B.

When I close Activity B I do it with finishaftertransition() it does it correctly.

If a configuration change occurs in Activity B then finishaftertransition() does not work but instead executes finish() directly and the animation is lost.

That could be happening?

I need to use finish aftertransition() because I need to execute code when the transition is finished and not lose the exit animation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.